# How to make a button thin (by height) in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a Python Tkinter-based GUI. And I need to add a thin, small-height button (see image below).
I tried to set height attribute to 0.5 (a float number), but it requires integers, so I got only this error:

> _tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "0.5"

I also noticed, that when I use pack (not grid) geometry manager, and if I resize the whole window, the button gets the required size:

[image: A thin button, when the window height is also small]

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
my_button = Button(root, text="A simple button")
my_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But I'm wondering how can I set the float button height right in the code? Maybe, there is something else except the "height" attribute?

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller font?

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you very much! Changing the font size works! But is there a way to create a button with a smaller height without using smaller font?

Comment: Did you mean `relief='flat'`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA thank you for the comment! Yes, I'm using the button with the "flat" relief (and a border around it). So I need to have a pretty big text and a smaller button size at the same time.

Comment: But it looks like that you used `relief='raised'`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes, in the minimal reproducible example I gave with the question because the button borders are the most visible in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! :) Question, that @stovfl gave helped me a lot :)